# Log runtime Exceptions in Java using log4j

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging, log4j

I am currently building an application using Tomcat, Spring and JAVA.  I am using `Log4J` as my logging library.  I currently am logging everything to a text file.  One of the issues I'm having is that `RuntimeExceptions` are not being logged to any files.  I was wondering if there is a way to log all `RuntimeExceptions` that maybe thrown to my application log file.  If not is it possible to have it log to another log file?  Is there a standard way to do this?  If so is there a standard way to do this when running your application within Tomcat?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you mean "uncaught" RuntimeExceptions?

Comment: Yes I mean "uncaught" RuntimeExceptions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is a handler for exceptions that terminate threads. It is a handler for any exception that is not caught explicitly by the target of the thread.

The default "uncaught exception handler" simply calls `printStackTrace()` on the `Throwable` to print the stack trace to `System.err`. However, you could [replace](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) this with your own [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) that logs the exception to log4j instead:

```
class Log4jBackstop implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

  private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jBackstop.class);

  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Uncaught exception in thread: " + t.getName(), ex);
  }

}
```

If you are using an executor framework to which you pass a `Runnable` object, its threads probably have their own `catch` block that prevent exceptions from reaching the uncaught exception handler. If you want to catch `Runtime` exceptions there, one way to do it is to wrap each task in a logging wrapper, like this:

```
class Log4jWrapper {

  private final Logger log;

  private final Runnable target;

  Log4jWrapper(Logger log, Runnable target) { 
    this.log = Objects.requireNonNull(log);
    this.target = Objects.requireNonNull(target); 
  }

  public void run() {
    try {
      target.run();
    } catch(RuntimeException ex) {
      log.error("Uncaught exception.", ex);
      throw ex;
    }
  }

}

...

Runnable realTask = ...;
executor.submit(new Log4jWrapper(Logger.getLogger(Whatever.class), realTask));
```

Comment: Is this normally how this RuntimeExceptions are handled in applications? I guess I'm wondering if this is a standard way of dealing with this.

Comment: Also I'm using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor from the Spring API, is this still something that can be done using this class?

Comment: This works great if there is a RuntimeException on the Runnable, however what if there is an Exception with the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor? Say it throws a RunTimeException because the Pool was configured in correct....this will still print to the console and not be logged....any suggestions?

Comment: You might need both, the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and the `Runnable` wrapper. The uncaught exception handler would be set on the application thread that is creating and initializing the executor, and submitting the task for execution. The wrapper is used on the tasks that are submitted. Spring has stupidly confused runtime exceptions with checked exceptions, so a solution that helps it out of that mess may not be pretty.

Answer (score 16):

One way to log uncaught RuntimeExceptions (or any uncaught Throwables for that matter) is to create a class that implements [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).  This class's `uncaughtException()` method would simply write the exception details to the log.  You can make the JVM call this exception handler whenever an uncaught RuntimeException terminates a thread by adding the line

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
```

to your code.

Comment: Where should I put that line of code `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());` please?

Answer (score 3):

You can try redirecting the StdErr to use your logger.  This should output the result of anything being written to your std err (which should include unhandled exceptions)

This blog post gives a good rundown on how to do the redirection into a FileHandler that is apart of your logger:

- [Redirecting System.out and System.err to a rolling log file (Nick Stephen's blog)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219202409/https://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and)