# Processing all exceptions in multiple streams

Tags: java, exception, stdout, stderr, throw

I want my program exceptions to be sent to **each** of the following, preferably simultaneously:

- the console which starts it (not necessarily)
- a gui
- a txt file.

How can I achieve this?

My attempts:

- `System.setErr(PrintStream err)` will forward all exceptions to a new stream. I am not able to state more than
  one stream though.
- Calling `System.setErr(PrintStream err)` on a manually written `OutputStream`:

  > "You can write your own stream class that forwards to multiple streams and call System.setOut on an instance of that class" – Jeffrey Bosboom

  I found a way to do this. It is very nasty though. It "collects" `PrintStream`'s `write`-bytes, puts them in a puffer (500 ms timeout) and finally shows it to the user (`Proceed`):

  ```
  /* ErrorOutput.java */
  public static t_ErrBuffer t_activeErrBuffer = new t_ErrBuffer("");
  public static void setStdErrToFile(final File file) {
      ps = new PrintStream(fos) {
          @Override
          public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
              byte[] bn = new byte[len];
              for (int i = off, j = 0; i < (len + off); i++, j++) {
                  bn[j] = buf[i];
              }
              String msg = null;
              try {
                  msg = new String(bn, "UTF-8");
              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {}
              if (msg.matches("[\\w\\W]*[\\w]+[\\w\\W]*")) { // ^= contains at least one word character
                  if( ! t_activeErrBuffer.isAlive() ) {
                      t_activeErrBuffer = new t_ErrBuffer(msg);
                      t_activeErrBuffer.start();
                  } else {
                      t_activeErrBuffer.interrupt();
                      t_activeErrBuffer = new t_ErrBuffer(t_activeErrBuffer.getErrBuffer() + "\n" + msg); // ^= append to buffer and restart.
                      t_activeErrBuffer.start();
                  }
              }
          }
      };
      System.setErr(ps);
  }

  /* t_ErrBuffer.java */
  public class t_ErrBuffer extends Thread {
      private String  errBuffer;
      public t_ErrBuffer(String buffer) {
          this.errBuffer = buffer;
      }
      protected class Proceed implements Runnable {
          public String msg = null;
          public Proceed(String msg) {
              this.msg = msg;
          }
          @Override
          public void run() {
              // todo PRINT ERROR MESSAGE: DO THINGS WITH msg: console, gui, JOptionPane
          }
      }
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              Thread.sleep(500); // collect error lines before output. Needed because PrintStream's "write"-method writes ErrorMessages in multiple pieces (lines)
              // each time some new exception line comes in, the thread is stopped, buffer is being appended and thread new started
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              return; // stop
          }
          // after 500 ms of wait, no new error message line has come in. Print the message out:
          Thread t_tmp = new Thread(new Proceed("\n" + this.errBuffer));
          t_tmp.start();
          return;
      }
      public String getErrBuffer() {
          return this.errBuffer;
      }
  }
  ```

  is this what I am expected to do?
- Create new exception class which does it for me. Would probably work, but other exceptions than that (IO, FileNotFound, ...) will still be treated the old way
- Instead of stating `[method name] throws Exception` I could enclose **all** of my code in try/catch-blocks, get the exception and forward it to a method of mine, like this:

  ```
  /* AnyMethod.java */
  // ...
  try {
      // ... do everything here
  } catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException e) {   // as many as you like
      ErrorOutput.crash(e);
  }
  // ...

  /* ErrorOutput.java */
  public static void crash(Exception e) {
      FileOutputStream fos_errOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File("ErrorOutput.txt"), true);

      // 1st
      if (!System.out.equals(fos_errOutput)) {
          System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " :");  // to console or the preferred StdOut
          e.printStackTrace();
      }       

      // 2nd
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Gui.frame, "THE PROGRAM HAS CRASHED!" + "\n\n" + e.getMessage() + "\n\nFor a more detailed report, see ErrorLog.txt");    // gui output

      // 3rd
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos_errOutput);
      ps.print(new Date().toString() + ":");  // write to file
      e.printStackTrace(ps);
      ps.close();

      // 4th
      System.exit(0); // this could also be "throw new Exception" etc., but I don't know why one should do that.
  }
  ```

  this would probably also work, but I'd have to put *everything* into try/catch-blocks. This cannot be good programming style at all.
- Using a logger:

  > "use log4j and set up a method to write to GUI and also to log to
  >   stdout, and file" – Scary Wombat

  Loggers only help me **printing** my exceptions into desired streams, but they don't help me catching them, right?

  > But you really should use a logging package for this -- even java.util.logging can do what you need – Jeffrey Bosboom

  I have to tell my logging package where and what to log. But this is exactly what I am searching for.

I now can, as user3159253 suggested, use `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` to catch unhandled exceptions specifically.

*What is the right way to handle **all** thrown exceptions the way I want them to?* What else do I have to consider apart from `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` and `System.setErr()`(see above)?

Comment: use log4j and set up a method to write to GUI and also to log to stdout, and file

Comment: You can write your own stream class that forwards to multiple streams and call `System.setOut` on an instance of that class.  (But you really should use a logging package for this -- even java.util.logging can do what you need, no dependencies required.)

Comment: Likely you need to use a standartized logging facility like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) or aforementioned [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) and set up a [Thread.UncoughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344654/log-runtime-exceptions-in-java-using-log4j

Comment: Do you really have a good reason to log all the exceptions - as well the catches ones as the other ones? Thousands ones occur in the background and you surely not want to know about them (just take the {{InterruptedException}} as example...

Comment: This might be a little off topic, but unless you are generating custom exception messages that are user-related or user-friendly, I will **STRONGLY** suggest against displaying exception messages on the GUI (i.e. as an error dialog of some kind).  Typically, exception messages are helpful to the developer, not the user.  Therefore, before showing message to the GUI, transform the message into something the user can make sense of or will help the user perform his/her task.  Also, pick your battles. There are exceptions the user can't do anything about, so why show it? (i.e. most NPEs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need get hold of all exception instances thrown from/within your thread (may be try/catch or `Thread.UncoughtExceptionHandler` or `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)`).

Then once you have the exception instance you can simply log it using log4j but configure Log4j appenders to send your exception messages to multiple destinations. You can use File, Console, JDBC, JMS etc types of appenders depending upon your requirement. Also it is best to wrap them with Async appender.

Refer - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html

About pushing the exception message to GUI, it can be implemented in various ways depending upon what tech stack your are using in your application. In our application we are storing the message events (only critical ones) in database which are then picked by event monitoring threads from server and then pushed back to GUI (JQuery, JavaScript) using [http://cometd.org/documentation/cometd-java](http://CometD).

Answer (score 2):

Creating an object that extends `PrintStream` should work. Whenever it receives a line, it can display it and log it as required. Alternatively, all exceptions can be caught and redirected into a method that receives an `Exception` as a parameter, and the method can take care of logging/displaying the exception, and terminating the program cleanly.