# Letting the presentation layer (JSF) handle business exceptions from service layer (EJB)

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, exception, ejb, optimistic-locking

The EJB method (using CMT) that updates an entity supplied :

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean update(Entity entity) throws OptimisticLockException {
    // Code to merge the entity.
    return true;
}
```

This will throw the `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException`, if concurrent update is detected which is to be handled precisely by the caller (a managed bean).

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    try {
        service.update((Entity) event.getObject())
    } catch(OptimisticLockException e) {
        // Add a user-friendly faces message.
    }
}
```

But doing so makes an additional dependency from the `javax.persistence` API on the presentation layer compulsory which is a design smell leading to tight-coupling.

In which exception should it be wrapped so that the *tight-coupling* issue can be omitted in its entirely? Or is there a standard way to handle this exception which in turn does not cause any service layer dependencies to be enforced on the presentation layer?

<sub>By the way, I found it clumsy to catch this exception in the EJB (on the service layer itself) and then return a flag value to the client (JSF).</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom service layer specific runtime exception which is annotated with [`@ApplicationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html) with `rollback=true`.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public abstract class ServiceException extends RuntimeException {}
```

Create some concrete subclasses for general business exceptions, such as constraint violation, required entity, and of course optimistic lock.

```
public class DuplicateEntityException extends ServiceException {}
```

```
public class EntityNotFoundException extends ServiceException {}
```

```
public class EntityAlreadyModifiedException extends ServiceException {}
```

Some of them can be thrown directly.

```
public void register(User user) {
    if (findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
        throw new DuplicateEntityException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

```
public void addToOrder(OrderItem item, Long orderId) {
    Order order = orderService.getById(orderId);

    if (order == null) {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Some of them need a global interceptor.

```
@Interceptor
public class ExceptionInterceptor implements Serializable {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object handle(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
        try {
            return context.proceed();
        }
        catch (javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException e) { // Can be thrown by Query#getSingleResult().
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(e);
        }
        catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            throw new EntityAlreadyModifiedException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Which is registered as default interceptor (on all EJBs) as below in `ejb-jar.xml`.

```xml
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
        <interceptor-class>com.example.service.ExceptionInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor>
</interceptors>
<assembly-descriptor>
    <interceptor-binding>
        <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
        <interceptor-class>com.example.service.ExceptionInterceptor</interceptor-class>
    </interceptor-binding>
</assembly-descriptor>
```

As a general hint, in JSF you can also have a global exception handler which just adds a faces message. When starting with [this kickoff example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464321/log-runtime-exceptions-using-log4j-in-jsf-web-application/30464553#30464553), you could do something like this in `YourExceptionHandler#handle()` method:

```
if (exception instanceof EntityAlreadyModifiedException) { // Unwrap if necessary.
    // Add FATAL faces message and return.
}
else {
    // Continue as usual.
}
```

Comment: This is a bit off-topic and perhaps, I will go with a separate question, if I am unable to get a solution. I have a test application containing only  an interceptor   (`javax.interceptor.Interceptor`) with configurations all mentioned here and a single EJB. I always get an exception on deployment - `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Interceptor binding contains an interceptor class  name = com.example.MyInterceptor that is not defined as an interceptor`. What might be the probable cause at a glance?

Comment: See updated answer for explicit registration. I guess GF4 won't do that if there's no `@InterceptorBinding`.

Comment: This works now. Thanks. (I did not expect explicitly registering an interceptor this way).

Comment: `Throwable exception = iter.next().getContext().getException();` in the `handle()` method in `ExceptionHandlerWrapper` always returns `javax.faces.FacesException` (`exception.getClass().getName()`). Therefore, a conditional check like `exception instanceof EntityAlreadyModifiedException` always fails even though `EntityAlreadyModifiedException` is re-thrown from the interceptor specified.

Comment: Comment says "Unwrap if necessary". If you're using [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Exceptions), use `Exceptions#unwrap()` or, better, `Exceptions#is()`.

Comment: Working well. Thank you.

Comment: Can exception stack-traces be suppressed so that they are not displayed on the server log? They are unnecessary at the point an appropriate `FacesMessage` is added.

Comment: Yes, override `FullAjaxExceptionHandler#logException()` to pass `null` as `exception` argument (as per [your comment on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534187/why-use-a-jsf-exceptionhandlerfactory-instead-of-error-page-redirection/10564549#comment50668743_10564549), you're most likely extending `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` for the purpose).