# Log4J 2: Uncaught Exceptions: Not being logged to file

Tags: testng, java-7, log4j2, uncaught-exception

I'm using Log4J 2 alongside TestNG and Java 7 with IntelliJ as the IDE for a web automation project.

I'm trying to redirect the standard error output of all uncaught Exceptions to a Log4J 2 log file with level ERROR.

I've created a subclass of an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` called `Log4J2UncaughtExceptionHandler` that is meant to log the uncaught exceptions to an output log file:

```
public class Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

Then in the code, I have set the default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` to this newly created handler instance:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler);
```

...and then I have verified that the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` has been changed:

```
// Prints "2016-10-31 15:15:19,623 INFO  [Test worker] plugins.Log4JUtils (Log4JUtils.java:89) - test.java.utils.Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler@118414c5"
Log4JUtils.logInfo(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().toString());
```

...but then I raise an uncaught exception:

```
String s = null;
s.charAt(0);
```

...and although the `NullPointerException` gets logged to the console for IntelliJ, it does not show up in the error file I've directed the error to.

Moreover, when I place a debug point in the above `uncaughtException()` method, the debugger does NOT stop there.

I am not sure why something like this is occurring. Are there some exceptions that are simply not tracked by `UncaughtExceptionHandlers`?

#### Stack trace

Here is the stack trace. I should note as well that the above consists of tests using Selenium and Firefox with a Gradle build. I've interjected the `NullPointerException` statements at the beginning of one of the test cases.

```
3:14:59 PM: Executing external task 'DEBUG_qa1TestFirefox'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56873', transport: 'socket'
:DEBUG_qa1TestFirefox

Default Suite STANDARD_OUT
    2016-10-31 15:15:08,044 INFO  [Test worker] plugins.Log4JUtils (Log4JUtils.java:89) - 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------ The test is starting now at 2016-10-31-15-15-08-031 ------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    15:15:08.044 [Test worker] INFO  test.java.utils.plugins.Log4JUtils - 
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------ The test is starting now at 2016-10-31-15-15-08-031 ------------
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Default Suite > Firefox STANDARD_OUT
    2016-10-31 15:15:08,084 INFO  [Test worker] plugins.Log4JUtils (Log4JUtils.java:89) - 
    -------------------------------------------------
    ------------ Testing case #[6.0]: [] ------------
    -------------------------------------------------
    15:15:08.084 [Test worker] INFO  test.java.utils.plugins.Log4JUtils - 
    -------------------------------------------------
    ------------ Testing case #[6.0]: [] ------------
    -------------------------------------------------
    2016-10-31 15:15:16,862 INFO  [Test worker] plugins.Log4JUtils (Log4JUtils.java:89) - Browser opened in FIREFOX
    15:15:16.862 [Test worker] INFO  test.java.utils.plugins.Log4JUtils - Browser opened in FIREFOX

Default Suite > Firefox > test.java.<censored> STANDARD_OUT
    2016-10-31 15:15:19,623 INFO  [Test worker] plugins.Log4JUtils (Log4JUtils.java:89) - test.java.utils.Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler@118414c5
    15:15:19.623 [Test worker] INFO  test.java.utils.plugins.Log4JUtils - test.java.utils.Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler@118414c5

Default Suite > Firefox > test.java.<censored> FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException at <censored>.java:543
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56873', transport: 'socket'

1 test completed, 1 failed
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/<censored>/build/reports/2016-10-31-03_15_04_628/Firefox/index.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 29.899 secs
3:15:29 PM: External task execution finished 'DEBUG_qa1TestFirefox'.
```

#### TestNG method

The TestNG method where the `NullPointerException` is being called:

```
@Test(groups = {group1, group2})
@TestMethodLabel(testNumber = 6, text = "")
public final void testMethod1() {

    // DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY: Force a NullPointerException to be thrown.
    Log4JUtils.logInfo(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().toString());

    String s = null;
    s.charAt(0);

    // <main test case code here>
}
```

#### Full code for handler

```
package <censored>;

import <censored>;

/**
 * A handler for uncaught exceptions.
 */
public class Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * Run any code necessary to handle the uncaught exception (e).
     *
     * Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the
     * Java Virtual Machine.
     *
     * @param t the thread from which the Exception has been declared.
     * @param e the exception to raise.
     */
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        Log4JUtils.OUTPUT_LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

#### Log4J2 configs (2 different files for stderr and stdout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="STDOUT_FILE" fileName="${sys:logFilePath}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
        </File>
        <File name="STDERR_FILE" fileName="${sys:errFilePath}" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            </Filters>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Console name="STDERR" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="test.java.utils.plugins.Log4JUtils" level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="WARN"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR" level="DEBUG"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR" level="FATAL"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="TRACE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR_FILE" level="ERROR"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT_FILE" level="INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT_FILE" level="WARN"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR_FILE" level="DEBUG"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDERR_FILE" level="FATAL"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT_FILE" level="TRACE"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

#### The logger being called

The logger being called is in a class called `Log4JUtils`. Also, the actual logger being called is substituted in for the dummy name of the logger (see Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler.java)

```
public class Log4JUtils {

    /**
     * The LOGGER for this class instance that writes output to log files.
     */
    private static final Logger OUTPUT_LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Log4JUtils.class.getName());

}
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace logs here as well please. For the NPE as seen in console.

Comment: Hi nullpointer, added the stack trace.

Comment: `test.java.utils.Log4JUncaughtExceptionHandler@118414c5` shall mean that the handler is being reached. To why its not getting logged in the file depends on the configs used for log4j

Comment: Also would suggest sharing complete implementations of the classes for handlers, interjected null pointer and log4j configs.

Comment: I've also been making sure that the stdout and stderr also gets directed to both the IntelliJ console _AND_ the log/error file.

Comment: In the handler class you're missing the declaration for `logger`.

Comment: nullpointer, the variable logger was simply a placeholder name for the real logger; I've substituted it in.

Comment: To all future visitors: I was also looking for a way to log all uncaught exceptions (although my project doesn't use the same frameworks apart from log4j2), read the first few paragraphs of this question, was excited and then disappointed when I read the entire question and saw that it seemed as it wouldn't work.
However, I found out that it does indeed work with my setup. So I can only recommend to try it - maybe it works for you like it does for me.
This question might also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344654/